# In NTFS EFS how is the symmetric key (FEK) generated?

Tags: windows, aes

I have some old backups that are encrypted using windows EFS and I no longer have access to the certificate used to encrypt the FEK symmetric key included in the files but I do have the password, user name and as well large portion of the actual binaries before encryption. I do know that AES used by EFS is not vulnerable to known plain text attack but I was hoping that with the above information I can figure out how windows generated the FEK symmetric key that are used to encrypt the file. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you can do that, you break entire EFS system.

Answer (score 3):

## FEK is random

Sorry. (But if it were any different, this would be terrible for EFS.)

Microsoft Corporation, TechNet, [*How EFS Works*](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc962103.aspx):

> When you save a file to be encrypted, a random cryptographic generator supplies a unique file encryption key (FEK), which is a fast symmetric key designed for bulk encryption. The FEK encrypts the data in blocks.

Comment: Thanks, but is't unique per user certificate or per file?

Comment: It`s gonna be 128 random bits. Unique to the this universe most likely (no doubles in our lifetime, [not unlike a UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)). And NO relation to anything. Not to the cert, not to the file. (And like I said: anything else would be weird/counter-intuitive/bad.)

Comment: So does this means that each file on the same folder encrypted by the same user would get a different FEK?!

Comment: Yes. This is the way it's supposed to be.